# What does a "standard formula interface to a data.frame" mean in R?

Tags: r, aggregate

The documentation for `aggregate` states:

> ‘aggregate.formula’ is a standard formula interface to ‘aggregate.data.frame’.

I am new to R, and I don't understand what this means.  Please explain!

Thanks!

Uri

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Jump to the middle of the examples section of `help(aggregate)` and you will see this:

```
 ## Formulas, one ~ one, one ~ many, many ~ one, and many ~ many:
 aggregate(weight ~ feed, data = chickwts, mean)
 aggregate(breaks ~ wool + tension, data = warpbreaks, mean)
 aggregate(cbind(Ozone, Temp) ~ Month, data = airquality, mean)
 aggregate(cbind(ncases, ncontrols) ~ alcgp + tobgp, data = esoph, sum)
```

Four different calls to `aggregate()`, all using the *formula* interface.  The way it is written above in what you quote has to do with method dispatching mechanism used throughout R.

Consider the first example:

```
R> class(weight ~ feed)
[1] "formula"
R> class(chickwts)
[1] "data.frame"
```

so aggregate dispatches on it first argument (of class `formula`). The way a formula gets resolved in R typically revolves around a `model.matrix`, I presume something similar happens here and an equivalent call is eventually execucted by `aggregate.data.frame`, using the second argument `chickwts`, a `data.frame`.

```
R> aggregate(weight ~ feed, data = chickwts, mean)
       feed  weight
1    casein 323.583
2 horsebean 160.200
3   linseed 218.750
4  meatmeal 276.909
5   soybean 246.429
6 sunflower 328.917
R>
```

What you asked isn't the easiest beginner question, I'd recommend a good thorough look at some of the documentation and a decent R book if you have one handy. (And other SO questions give recommendation as to what to read next.)

*Edit:* I had to dig a little as `aggregate.formula()` is not exported from `stats` namespace, but you can look at it by typing `stats:::aggregate.formula` at the prompt -- which then clearly shows that it does, in fact, dispatch to `aggregate.data.frame()`:

```
 [.... some code omitted ...]
    if (is.matrix(mf[[1L]])) {
        lhs <- as.data.frame(mf[[1L]])
        names(lhs) <- as.character(m[[2L]][[2L]])[-1L]
        aggregate.data.frame(lhs, mf[-1L], FUN = FUN, ...)
    }
    else aggregate.data.frame(mf[1L], mf[-1L], FUN = FUN, ...)
}
<environment: namespace:stats>
R>
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this without naming all of the columns in `cbind()`? For multiple columns, I guess I don't understand why one can't do `aggregate(. ~ var, ...)` or names <- c("var1", "var2", ...)` and then `aggregate(df[, names] ~ var, ...)`. Or is this just not possible?